# Jenkins Date Parameter Plugin - How to use it in a Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

What is the syntax for using the Date Parameter Plugin in a declarative pipeline.

So far I have tried this:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
        label 'grange-jenkins-slave'
    }
}

options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }

parameters {
    date(name: 'EffectiveDate',
            dateFormat: 'MMddyyy',
            defaultValue: 'LocalDate.now();',
            description: 'Effective Date',
            trim: true)
    file(name:'algo.xlsx', description:'Your algorithm file')
    choice(name: 'currency',
            choices: ['USD'],
            description: 'Select a currency')

}
stages {
    stage('genRates') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The error I get is `WorkflowScript: 11: Invalid parameter type "date". Valid parameter types: [booleanParam, choice, credentials, file, text, password, run, string] @ line 11, column 3.`

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

you can define parameter [as class DateParameterDefinition](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/hubot-steps/).

example:

```
properties([parameters([
  string(name: 'somestring', defaultValue: 'somevalue'),
  [$class: 'DateParameterDefinition',
   name: 'somedate',
   dateFormat: 'yyyyMMdd',
   defaultValue: 'LocalDate.now()']
])])

pipeline {
...
}
```

Comment: The example is a perfect syntax. Just beware while copy paste with the coma if you have other paremeters.

Comment: For me it only works if I use it without the default value, but this is definitely the right and most helpful answer to this question!

Answer (score 1):

I did not use date parameter plugin as I didn't find any example how to use it. I resolved this in a different way.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
def dateDefaultValue = sdf.format(new Date())

pipeline {
     parameters {
        string(name: 'SOMEDATE', defaultValue: "${dateDefaultValue}", description: 'Default value is current date in the format YYYYmmdd', trim: true)
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```